# Restrict a method call to a specific page in a .net application (in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, conditional-statements

Hei, I have a method from a class in a custom library which I would like to restrict to be called only on a specific page, somehow using conditional methods. The problem is that I need a return value and conditional methods do not allow return other than void or 'out' parameters.
Using a void method it works fine, but is there a way to accomplish this kind of conditional behavior and still return a value?
Of course in the end I could manage like it is shown below, but I'm curious about other options.

My code now:

in the library:

```
public bool MyResult {get; private set;}

[Conditional("condition")]
public void MyConditionalMethod(...){
    this.MyResult = DoSomethingElse();
}
```

in the page:

```
#define condition
bla bla bla
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure conditional methods are what you are looking for? It seems unrelated to your wish to *restrict (the method) to be called only on a specific page*. Preprocessor symbols are build specific, not page specific.

Comment: After thinking about it for quite some time I realized that it would not really work using conditional methods... I have to come up with another solution. I wanted to avoid that a method is called from outside a certain context... ok, maybe I will create another question explaining better what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [C# Spec, chapter 17, verse 4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) explicitly says:

> The conditional method must have a return type of void.

I guess it's not possible with C# in this universe.

Yet.